# How do you run an nslookup on an iPhone?

Tags: domain-name-system, iphone, nslookup

Folks,
I'm trying to diagnose a connectivity issue between various iOS clients on AT&T scattered across the country and my website. They appear to be able to access my website by IP address but not by domain name while on AT&T 3G. WiFi is able to access my website by domain name just fine. I would like to know what the results of an nslookup when run by these various clients while connected over 3G.

There are lots of nslookup apps on the app store; unfortunately I believe all of them are using a remote nslookup service and not actually showing me what the device itself believes to be the IP addy of my website given its domain.

Can anyone recommend how I can run an nslookup on the iPhone? It would be great if one of my clients could tether his PC to the phone and run nslookup from the command line, but I don't think any of these people pay for AT&T tethering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have nslookup, but the app "zTools" has dig, ping, traceroute, portsscanner, etc

Answer (score 0):

http://software.terminal.dk/

Descriptions sounds like this one does the actual work on the device-- at least for ping and traceroute. Web site has links to the app store, and you could always ask the dev for specifics.

Disclaimer: I've not used this app, and have no other knowledge re the devs.

Comment: Good idea, I have just emailed him.

Comment: From the author: "It uses the DNS server that the phone is configured to use. That is typically the one from your phone provider if you are not on wireless.

And upcoming version will allow changing DNS server inside the app settings."